# reordering columns with AWK

Tags: command-line, awk, multiple-columns

I need to reorder the columns of this (tab-separated) data:

```
   1 cat    plays
   1 dog    eats
   1 horse  runs
   1 red    dog
   1 the    cat
   1 the    cat
```

so that is prints like:

```
cat plays   1
dog eats    1
horse   runs    1
red dog 1
the cat 2
```

i have tried:

```
sort [input] | uniq -c | awk '{print $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $1}' > [output]
```

and the result is:

```
1   cat 1
1   dog 1
1   horse   1
1   red 1
2   the 1
```

Can anyone give me some insight on what is going wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Others have answered your question. As a matter of style, I'd write `awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $3, $4, $1}'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the output of `cat input | sort | uniq -c` is:

```
   1    1 cat    plays
   1    1 dog    eats
   1    1 horse  runs
   1    1 red    dog
   2    1 the    cat
```

you need something like:

```
cat input | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $1}'
```

And we can also indicate the output field separator in awk:

```
cat input | sort | uniq -c | awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $3,$4,$1}'
```

Comment: Note that if you have spaces in your values, `awk` will split on them. To avoid that, and restrict separators to tabs only, pass this extra argument: `awk -F $'\t' ...`

Answer (score 3):

`uniq -c` adds an extra column. This should give you the output you want:

```
$ sort file | uniq -c | awk '{print $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $1}'
cat     plays   1
dog     eats    1
horse   runs    1
red     dog     1
the     cat     2
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` and `sort`:

```
$ awk '{a[$2 OFS $3]++}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' OFS='\t' file | sort -nk3 
cat     plays   1
dog     eats    1
horse   runs    1
red     dog     1
the     cat     2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU awk (gawk), you could use only it and its feature function `asorti()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gawk -f
{
    a[$2 "\t" $3]++
}
END {
    asorti(a, b)
    for (i = 1; i in b; ++i) print b[i] "\t" a[b[i]]
}
```

One line:

```
gawk '{++a[$2"\t"$3]}END{asorti(a,b);for(i=1;i in b;++i)print b[i]"\t"a[b[i]]}' file
```

Output:

```
cat plays   1
dog eats    1
horse   runs    1
red dog 1
the cat 2
```

UPDATE: To preserve original order without sorting use:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
!a[$2 "\t" $3]++ {
    b[++i] = $2 "\t" $3
}
END {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j) print b[j] "\t" a[b[j]]
}
```

Or

```
awk '!a[$2"\t"$3]++{b[++i]=$2"\t"$3}END{for(j=1;j<=i;++j)print b[j]"\t"a[b[j]]}' file
```

Any awk version would be compatible with that this time.

Output should be the same this time since input is already sorted by default.